# Smart App Banner showing as blank, gray bar

Tags: ios, ios6, meta-tags

I added the smart app banner meta tag to my page and it was working fine at one point yesterday. However, now the banner only appears as a gray bar with no content in it. It appears to try to load something for a second, but then stops. Not sure what I changed in the code that would break it. Link for screenshot included below or see for yourself live:

http://grahamgram.com

[image: screen-capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the service is currently down.

Been having the same problem myself, have just tested the ted.com site and theirs doesn't load either.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. That appears to be the problem. Not sure why I didn't check that myself. We'll see how long it takes to fix.

Answer (score 2):

the reason could be:

1. you are using a wrong app-id
2. your app and your apple-id (the one you use for app store) belong to different countries
3. you are using a proxy to test this smart banner in your dev env (so itunes cannot get the infomation, you can try to download the app from app store with proxy)
4. other reasons like the first answer

Comment: Followed every step on [the smart banner doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners) but still facing the same problem