# Apple smart banner is showing empty bar in ios safari (id correct in metatag)

Tags: ios, iphone, smartbanner

So about a year ago I implemented the smart banner for a ios app on a mobile website.
It worked fine until I saw earlier today that it is empty.

I looked at the id in the meta tag. But it is correct.

Screenshot:

[image: http://sup.urb.li/1huyf]

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=[ID]">
```

Can't find it myself, so help would be appreciated

iOS 9+
iPhone 5+

### iOS emulator on mac mini

all the same effect (see screenshot)

Thanks !

Comment: I am seeing this issue for my app as well on an iPhone 5

Comment: @peterdoesco.de did you ever find a working solution? Im getting this same thing new except mine disappears after a second or two

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by only using the numeric part of the App Store id:

`<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=698632628">`

Comment: That's right as the official documentations says : app-id: (Required.) Your app's unique identifier. To find your app ID from the iTunes Link Maker, type the name of your app in the Search field, and select the appropriate country and media type. In the results, find your app and select iPhone App Link in the column on the right. Your app ID is the nine-digit number in between id and ?mt.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html):

> Banners won’t appear in the iOS Simulator.

Your tag looks fine.
If you test it on an actual device the banner should display properly.

The reason for this is probably that the banner has to pull the information from the app store (including whether the app is installed on the device), which is not present on the simulator.

If the banner does not properly display on an actual device the reason could be that the associated service of apple is currently not available as mentioned in the following post: [Smart App Banner showing as blank, gray bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308976/smart-app-banner-showing-as-blank-gray-bar)

Comment: Its tested on iOS 9+ iPhone 5+ AND emulator as described.